# Generalized Poincare conjecture from h-cobordism

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

I am interesting in the notion of cobordism.
 In particular, I want to understand Smale's proof of Poincare conjecture
 in higher dimention.
 In a webpage, I knew that the proof is followed by h-cobordism shortly.
 However, I do not notice that proof.

Please tell me how to proof it.
 I like simple proof diagramatic and know h-cobordism theorem.

Thank you for your considerations.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at Milnor's "Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem". As with everything written by him, it's a great read!

Comment: Kosinski's textbook is also a good book to read with Milnor's notes. 

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have not ever read these book. I try!
 

Comment: The thing I don't like about Milnor's notes is that he scrupulously avoids talking about handles, always working directly with the Morse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to prevent this question from resurfacing periodically due to the lack of an answer, here's a summary of the answers that are in the comments.

- Milnor's "Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem"
- Kosinski's "Differential Manifolds"

Comment: Thanks. I have just discovered that Milnor's note have a proof of Poincare conjecture in higher dimension.